# terraform: modify lb listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a terraform script where I use a module `dcos-terraform/dcos/aws` to setup my infra, I then make certain modifications like route52 rules and load balancer certificates etc. I am trying to modify the NLB 443 protocol to TLS from TCP with a certificate, but terraform tries to create a new one instead and fails.

```
...
# i get the load balancer, target group and listeners
data "aws_lb" "ext-lb" {
  name = "ext-${var.cluster_name}"
}
data "aws_lb_target_group" "ext-tg-443" {
  name     = "ext-${var.cluster_name}-tg-443"
}
data "aws_lb_listener" "public-front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${data.aws_lb.ext-lb.arn}"
  port = "443"
}

# i then need to modify the listener but throws Duplicate port error as it tries to make a new one instead of modifying it.
resource "aws_lb_listener" "public-front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${data.aws_lb.ext-lb.arn}"
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "TLS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${data.aws_lb_target_group.ext-tg-443.arn}"
  }
}

# i also tried this, but it requires the port to already be TLS and not TCP
resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "public-certificate" {
  listener_arn    = "${data.aws_lb_listener.public-front_end.arn}"
  certificate_arn = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
}

...
```

my current workaround is running a null_resource - local-exec cli script.

```
#! /bin/bash

current_protocol="NA"
current_protocol="$(aws elbv2 describe-listeners --listener-arn $1 --output text --query 'Listeners[0].Protocol')"
if [ $current_protocol == "TCP" ]
then
    aws elbv2 delete-listener --listener-arn $1
    echo "listener deleted"
else
    echo "listener ok"
fi
```

modified tf file

```
resource "null_resource" "update-nlb" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sh update-nlb-script.sh ${data.aws_lb_listener.public-front_end.arn}"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "public-front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${data.aws_lb.ext-lb.arn}"
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "TLS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${data.aws_lb_target_group.ext-tg-443.arn}"
  }

  depends_on = [
    "null_resource.update-nlb"
  ]
}
```

this runs fine if you run once, but if I re-run the `terrraform plan` command, then tf wants re re-add the listener I deleted but now it can't add because I have another listener in it's place. This returns an error.

sample tf file https://gist.github.com/Rohithzr/c846de2fa7e5fd133dfd1549c0e104b5

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like an error in Terraform; it should be marking the resource for destruction and then replacing it.

If you don’t have it defined elsewhere, are you able to taint the current resource?

That will allow you to change it out cleanly.

Comment: that's what I thought, the problem I feel is that the resource is created at `module.dcos.module.dcos-infrastructure.module.dcos-lb.module.dcos-lb-public-agents.module.public-agents.aws_lb_listener.listeners` path by another module, and I dont have access to edit the module itself.

Comment: @RohitHazra as of v0.12 you should be able to taint the nested module resource as if it’s a normal resource.

Comment: Oh, these facts seem to block both below solution suggestions. As long as the resource is terraform managed it will overwrite any changes at the next apply.

Comment: @Ryder well 0.12 has an issue, the module is not compatible with it, so unfortunately I am stuck with 0.11

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are using a new terraform file, and try to create a new "terraform resource" "aws_lb_listener". As terraform does not have this resource in its state it treats it as new.

Two possible ways to resolve the situation:

- Use terraform import to import the listener into the state. Then modify it with terraform.
- Modify the listener with aws cli.

Comment: well technically it's the same file, here is the link https://gist.github.com/Rohithzr/c846de2fa7e5fd133dfd1549c0e104b5

Comment: the cli is the current workaround I have, but once I run this, and re-run the plan command, it wants to re-add the listener I deleted from the cli

Comment: Why not simply checkout the dcos module from git as files, and modify it there?

Comment: it's a possibility, it is just quite a complex terraform script https://github.com/dcos-terraform/terraform-aws-dcos/blob/master/main.tf that uses other scripts and that uses more scripts :(

Comment: The path seems to be already clear: `module.dcos.module.dcos-infrastructure.module.dcos-lb.module.dcos-lb-public-agents.module.public-agents.aws_lb_listener.listeners`

Comment: well @hargut thanks for the suggestion, maybe i will end up cloning a bunch of repos, or maybe I will propose a different type of PR to them.

Comment: Check the `.terraform` folder after the init, the files should already be there. In the best case a copy to the main folder could work out as easy fix.